# printf not printing variables

Tags: c, cs50

I'm doing CS50's Caesar problem, which requires me to move the letters of a string one forward (A -> B). It worked with a simple `letter++` but when I try to move the letter a specific amount, nothing's working. Any help?

```
string p = get_string("plaintext: ");
int k = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
printf("ciphertext: ");
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p); i++)
{
    printf("%c", (p[i] + k) % 26);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(p[i] + k) % 26` should be `'A' + ((p[i]-'A' + k) % 26)`

Comment: ...or is it just printing non-printable characters?

Comment: @IlyaBursov That works, thanks! If it's not too much effort, would you kindly explain what that did?

Comment: *Is* there an `argv[1]`? You should always check `argc >= 2` first, if only to protect you from yourself.

Comment: it converts letters from ascii code to number and back

Comment: `string`.  No.  Just no.  Do not use CS50's benighted `string` type.  Ever.  It is extremely confusing.

Comment: @OmidGhafori, taking a value modulo 26 (`% 26`) gives you a number between 0 to 25, but 'A' to 'Z' ranges from 65 to 90 in ASCII, so you end up printing completely different characters after the modulo. Ilya's solution takes the modulo of the offset from 'A' (instead of the actual value of the letter), then adds that modulo'd value back to 'A'.

Comment: Using `string` is reprehensible. Assuming ASCII encoding saddens me.

Answer (score 0):

It prints some invisible characters among first 26 characters of ASCII table. You need to print `'A' + (alphabet_index(i)+k)%26` where `alphabet_index(i) = i - 'A'`